# QFile,QFile::open: File access not specified, Opening file failed

Tags: qt, file

Simple problem, I just can't open/create a file. It's supposed to save some settings in an xml-file to a given path.

I call the method like this:

xmlwriter->write_settings("./settings.xml");

```
int XmlWriter::write_settings(QString path)
{
    qDebug() << "Path is: " + path;

    QDomDocument document;

    QDomElement root = document.createElement("settings");
    document.appendChild(root);

    QDomElement node;
    node.setAttribute("name", "Its me!");
    node.setAttribute("series", "25");
    node.setAttribute("PMT", "200");

    root.appendChild(node);

    QFile file(path);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite, QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Opening file failed!";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << document.toString();
        file.close();
        qDebug() << "wrote file to " + path;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the path look like?

Comment: well its "./settings.xml"

Comment: Did you tried absolute path? I think you need to post an error for clarity

Comment: I tried an absolute path too. The error is this "QFile::open: File access not specified".

Comment: Check the access rights for your file. What OS do you use?

Comment: Yes I tried "/home/username/settings.xml". I'm on a Linux.

Comment: `chmod 777 /home/username/settings.xml`. Can you access this file with another programs?

Comment: No it's supposed to be created. Rights should be ok because I'm the owner of my home folder. Also changed settings.xml to chmod 777.

Comment: Also `file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite, QIODevice::Text)` is a mistake, you wanted to write `file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)` I think

Comment: Works! it was just the little |, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass parameters correctly, so you probably invoke a polymorphic version of `QFile::open`

Try this:

```
QFile file(path);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
{
      qDebug() << "Opening file failed!";
     return 1;
}
else
{
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << document.toString();
    file.close();
    qDebug() << "wrote file to " + path;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but `file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite, QIODevice::Text)` equals to `file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)`, so I don't think it causes an error

Comment: I don't think it equals, in its version he invokes `bool open ( int fd, OpenMode mode )` because the first parameter will take the first place and the second the second. And the fd will indicate an incorrect file descriptor

Comment: It was `open(int fd, OpenMode mode, FileHandleFlags handleFlags = DontCloseHandle)` I think, so you're right